# How to extract a pointer size in C

Tags: c, pointers, size

i have code like this:

```
int main()
{
    double *u;
    int len;
    u=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*10);
    len = sizeof(u);
    printf("Length Of Array = %d\n", len);
    return 0;
}
```

but the length is 4 Not 10.
how can i extract 10 from pointer u?!
please help me
thank you

Comment: Seems like you want the size of the allocated memory. You just can't get it this way. (and any other way)

Comment: You know how much memory you allocated - you have to keep track of it.

Comment: means there is no other way ?

Comment: It is in the argument passed to `malloc(sizeof(double)*10)`. In this case where you are the one who allocated the memory, you *already* know the size - provided `malloc` did not return `NULL`, which you have not checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer doesn't include information about the size of the memory area. You have to keep track of the size yourself. For instance, you can make a custom type (for example, a `struct`) that contains both the pointer and the size of the allocation at the same time.

Here's a simple implementation to get you started:

```c
typedef struct {
  double* ptr;
  size_t len;
} double_arr_t;

// prototype
double_arr_t alloc_double_arr(size_t len);

int main(void) {
  // alloc the new array of 10 `double` elements
  double_arr_t arr = alloc_double_arr(10);
  printf("Length of 'arr' is %zu\n", arr.len); // Length of 'arr' is 10

  // assign a value to the first element
  arr.ptr[0] = 3.14;
  // get the value of the first element
  double first_element = arr.ptr[0];

  // free the array when you're done using it
  free(arr.ptr);
}

double_arr_t alloc_double_arr(size_t len) {
  double_arr_t res;
  res.ptr = malloc(len * sizeof(double));
  res.len = len;
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That's your job. C does not provide a portable way of knowing, given a pointer, how much memory has been allocated.

`sizeof` will give you `sizeof(double*)`, that's all. That's 4 on your system.

Comment: means there is no other way ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. `sizeof` is giving the size of the object. In your case the object is `u` which is a pointer. Your system is 32 bits as pointers are 4 bytes.

if you sizeof(*u)- you will get the size of referenced type. In this case it is the `double` . It will be 8 bytes long at most systems.

using `sizeof` to get the size of the length of the string is one of the most frequent questions asked here.

Comment: Note that in the evaluation of `sizeof(*u)`, `u` is not dereferenced, so `u` doesn't need to point to an object.